# Open app through notification banner when app is not running state iOS

Tags: ios

I have tabbar controller having three tab, attached three navigation controller I want to go to second controller of navigation controller just like whatsapp. I handled successfully for background state, but for not running state. Below is my code in didfinishlaunch delegate method of uiapplication.

```
if (launchOptions != nil) {
        // Launched from push notification

        NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];


        [self performSelector:@selector(notificationObserverAfterDelay:) withObject:notification afterDelay:2.0];

    }

-(void)notificationObserverAfterDelay:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefreshUIChatNotRunningState" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: Is your view controller with tabBar is your rootViewController ?? What will be the state of navigation stack when your view controller with tab bar is loaded ??? Throwing notifictaion with delay is in my view bad approach

Comment: Having one controller in navigation stack. I want to add one more through segue.

Comment: this oneViewController is the one having tab bar ??? So your rootViewController is UINavigationController and its navigationStack has yourViewController with tab bar correct ???

Comment: yes one viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Nazish Ali,

Sending out notification after delay of 2 seconds is really not a good idea.

Declare a method which accepts your userInfo dictionary as argument in your viewController having tab bar.

lets call it as,

*YourViewController.h*

```
-(void)appStartedFromPushNotification : (NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

*YourViewController.m*

```
-(void)appStartedFromPushNotification : (NSDictionary *)userInfo {
       //now the control has reached yourViewController with tab bar
       //change the tab bar selection and perform segue and load the next viewController and use prepareforSgue to pass the data
}
```

Now why YourViewController only why not the actualViewController which anyway needs to be loaded ??? Reason you dont want mess with navigation stack manually. Because YourViewController is the child of UINavigationController and UINavigationController is your rootView controller YourViewController will be loaded automatically. So just access it and ask it to perform the tab change and load viewControllers so your navigation stack will continue to be stable :)

finally in Appdelegate,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (launchOptions) {
        [self handleReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Declare a method in AppDelegate.m and access the YourViewController instance and handover data to it thats all :)

```
- (void) handleReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    UINavigationController *rootViewController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    for(UIViewController *viewController in rootViewController.viewControllers){

        if([viewController isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) {
                [viewController appStartedFromPushNotification:userInfo];
        }
}
```

That should do the job :) Happy coding :)